# Gradle - Android - add version code number as versionNameSuffix to debug buildTypes

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-configchanges, android-build-type

I want to add the version code as a suffix of versionNameSuffix.
Currently, I have:

```
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix ".debug"
    }
```

How can I have something like:

```
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix ".debug.versionCode"
    }
```

My version code is based on the productFlavors:

```
    productFlavors {
        free {
            versionCode 123
        }
    }
```

@Resolution: I move versionCode out from productFlavors to root level and use the accepted anwser to inject versionCode in versionNameSuffix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create constant version code in your app `build.gradle`

`def versionCode = 1`

Then in your flavours

```
debug {
    versionNameSuffix ".debug.${versionCode}”
}
```

Use the same version code in your defaultconfig also

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode ${versionCode}        
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, since I have versionCode basing on productFlavors, how can I get the versionCode? I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Try to create diffrent constants for different flavors.